# Authentications that can continue: publickey,password

Tags: ssh, passwords

I'm triyng to use ssh connection from my windows terminal to debian.

i'm using ssh -v xxx@yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy but it keep ask me for a password.

```
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.4.3
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: Connecting to yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy [yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/id_ed25519 type 3
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.9p1 Debian-10+deb10u2
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_7.9p1 Debian-10+deb10u2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy:22 as 'xxx'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519SSSSSSSSThgPWai6sDSSSSS
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host 'yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/known_hosts:7
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or directory
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:HSSSSShkgzBcKaQFFonaywflrJHSSSSS
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:R/m8t6SSSSSrkeYcFVouP50UbycQ45SSSSSS
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:HYCXDkqF1LdSSSSlrJH4+ASSSSS
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Offering public key: C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:R/m8t60ESrkeYcFVouP50UbycQNfBSSSSSSSS
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\User/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

I'm create id_rsa or id_rd25519 key on my debian (root/.ssh/) and i put private key on my windows.
Why I my id_rsa key or id-ed25519 key not working ?

thanks

I''m trying to connect by ssh without password